# Golang unable to add sub modules from subfolder in vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, go-gin

I've got a golang little rest app and I've created a new folder `routes` and new file `book.go` (and others similar to this)

`routes/book.go`

```
package routes

import (
    "golang-example-rest/controllers"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func bookRouter(r *gin.RouterGroup) {
    r.GET("/", controllers.FindBooks)
    r.POST("/", controllers.CreateBook)
    r.GET("/:id", controllers.FindBook)
    r.PATCH("/:id", controllers.UpdateBook)
    r.DELETE("/:id", controllers.DeleteBook)
}
```

but in the root `main.go` file the import `golang-example-rest/routes` get continuously removed from vscode as soon as i save and then routes remain unknown (imports from controllers and models works as expected)...

`/main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "golang-example-rest/models"
    "golang-example-rest/routes"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    models.ConnectDatabase()

    r.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": "hello world"})
    })

    routes.bookRouter(r.Group("/books"))
    routes.companyRouter(r.Group("/companies"))
    routes.specialtyRouter(r.Group("/specialties"))

    r.Run()
}
```

`/go.sum`

```
module golang-example-rest

go 1.21.3

require (
```

do I need to run specific commands in go or do I need do something else?

I am working on Windows on WSL.

Comment: You are not talking about submodules but packages. Whatever you export from `routes` needs to start with uppercase letter as that tells compiler it should be visible outside the `routes` package - e.g. `routes.BookRouter`. Your import is probably removed by VSCode because it is seen as unused as lowercase starting things are not “seen” by whatever linter VSCode uses (I am not VSCode user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bookRouter` needs to be exported from package `routes` to be available in package `main`.

Since `routes.bookRouter` and other similar lines do not refer to exported functions of `routes`, and `routes` is not used elsewhere, `routes` is not used by the file so tooling like `goimports`/`gopls`/etc used by VS Code removes the import.

Change `bookRouter` to `BookRouter` to be able to access the function from outside the package.